# Выбор случайных значений MySQL

Tags: mysqli

Добрый день.
Есть скрипт на выбор данных по дням рождения в таблице `employee.congratulations_text` хранится по 10 поздравлений для каждого пола. Необходимо выбрать именинников на текущую дату + для них уникальные тексты поздравлений, в зависимости от пола.

Пробовал несколько способов, получается не совсем то, что надо.

```
Способ 1:

    select distinct 
             t1.ID,
             t1.FIO,
             t1.GENDER,
             t2.EMAIL,
             t3.TEXT
        from employee.employee_data        as t1
        join employee.employee_contact     as t2 on t2.ID = t1.ID
        join employee.congratulations_text as t3 on t3.GENDER = t1.GENDER
       where day(t1.BIRTHDAY) = day(curdate()) -- выбрать текущий день
         and month(t1.BIRTHDAY) = month(curdate()) -- выбрать текущий месяц
       order by rand()
       limit @a

    Способ 2:

        select distinct 
                 t1.ID,
                 t1.FIO,
                 t1.GENDER,
                 t2.EMAIL,
                 t3.TEXT
            from employee.employee_data    as t1
            join employee.employee_contact as t2 on t2.ID = t1.ID
            join (select TEXT,GENDER from employee.congratulations_text order by rand() limit @a) as t3 on t3.GENDER = t1.GENDER
           where day(t1.BIRTHDAY) = day(curdate()) -- выбрать текущий день
             and month(t1.BIRTHDAY) = month(curdate()) -- выбрать текущий месяц

-----------
limit @a - переменная, которая содержит кол-во именинников на каждую дату
```

В чем проблема / что не получается:

- Итоговый набор содержит дубли именинников;
- Например, если именинников 2, итоговый набор может содержать 2 одинаковые записи по одному человеку, записей по другому нет.

Comment: Не может быть, что записи полностью дублируются, какое нибудь поле наверняка отличается. например если у человека в контактах будет 2 записи с разными email то на выходе вы этого человека 2 раза и получите, только с разными email. Для начала вам надо определится, что делать в таких случаях, какой именно контакт вас интересует. Кроме того вся выборка будет буквально помножена на таблицу congratulations_text для каждого именинника будут подклеены _все_ записи поздравлений. А что там в итоге limit обрежет - это как повезет

Comment: А текст поздравления тогда лучше получить подзапросом прямо в списке выборки, и там сделать разумеется limit 1

Comment: пробовал и так и так, как Вы описали. Возможно, я неправильно описал актуальный результат. Бывает случай когда по 1-му сотруднику 2 записи с разными текстами поздравлений. А 2-ой комментарий Ваш, тоже пробовал, тогда получается, что у 2-х сотрудников одинаковый текст поздравления. + если будет так, что именинник муж. и жен. пола, а поздравление одно - это неправильно...

Comment: `select id, fio, ..., (select text from congratulations_text t3 where t3.gender=t1.gender order by rand() limit 1) text from t1 ...` обязано работать

Comment: Mike, благодарю, подошло, спасибо за помощь, хорошего дня.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ на вопрос (спасибо Mike):

```
          select t1.ID, 
                 t1.FIO, 
                 t1.GENDER,
                 t2.EMAIL,
                 (select text from congratulations_text as t3 where t3.gender = t1.gender order by rand() limit 1) as 'TEXT'
            from employee_birthday.employee_data        as t1
            join employee_birthday.employee_contact     as t2 on t2.ID = t1.ID
           where day(t1.BIRTHDAY) = day(curdate())
             and month(t1.BIRTHDAY) = month(curdate())
```